# Probability of coprime polynomials

Tags: nt.number-theory, polynomials, finite-fields, pr.probability

Given positive integer $N$, we choose $m_1, m_2, n_1, n_2$ independently and with equal probabilities from $\{0,1,\ldots,N\}$, and let 
$f_1 = x^{m_1} + (1+x)^{n_1}$ and $f_2 = x^{m_2} + (1+x)^{n_2}$ as polynomials in the indeterminate $x$ over the field ${\mathbb F}_2$ of two elements.  Let $P(N)$ be the probability  that $f_1$ and $f_2$ are coprime.  What can be said about $P(N)$, in particular its asymptotics as $N \to \infty$?

By explicit enumeration in Maple, the first few values are
$$\eqalign{P \left( 1 \right) &={\frac {9}{16}},P \left( 2 \right) ={\frac {56}{
81}},P \left( 3 \right) ={\frac {45}{64}},P \left( 4 \right) ={\frac {
489}{625}},P \left( 5 \right) ={\frac {1019}{1296}},\cr P \left( 6
 \right) &={\frac {1895}{2401}},P \left( 7 \right) ={\frac {3299}{4096}
},P \left( 8 \right) ={\frac {5308}{6561}},P \left( 9 \right) ={\frac 
{2023}{2500}},P(10) = \frac{11954}{14641}\cr}$$ 
Random sampling seems to indicate $P(100) \approx 0.83$. The sequence $(N+1)^4 P(N)$
does not appear to be in the OEIS.

EDIT: That sequence is now in the OEIS as [A245488](https://oeis.org/A245488).
$P(100) = 86648767/101^4 \approx 0.8326776196$.

Answer (score 11):

(Edited in response to Julian Rosen's comments)

As $N\to\infty$, one could guess that $P(N)$ approaches
$$
\prod_{p} \Bigl(1 - \Bigl(\frac{\gcd(a_p,b_p)}{a_p b_p}\Bigr)^2\Bigr),
$$
where the product is over all irreducibles $p(x)\in\mathbf{F}_2[x]$ of degree at least $2$, and $a_p$ and $b_p$ denote the orders of $x$ and $x+1$ in the multiplicative group of $\mathbf{F}_2[x]/(f(x))$, respectively.  This is because this group is cyclic, so the intersection of subgroups of orders $a_p$ and $b_p$ has order $\gcd(a_p,b_p)$.  Then the number of pairs $(m,n)$ with $1\le m\le a_p$ and $1\le n\le b_p$ for which $p\mid x^m+(1+x)^n$ is $\gcd(a_p,b_p)$, so if $N$ is large compared to $a_p$ and $b_p$ then the proportion of the pairs $(m,n)$ with $0\le m,n\le N$ for which $p\mid x^m+(1+x)^n$ will approach $\gcd(a_p,b_p)/(a_pb_p)$.  Hence the probability that $p$ divides both $x^{m_1}+(1+x)^{n_1}$ and $x^{m_2}+(1+x)^{n_2}$ approaches the square of $\gcd(a_p,b_p)/(a_pb_p)$, which yields the claimed formula.

However, as Julian Rosen points out, I'm implicitly assuming the independence of divisibility by distinct primes $p$, which isn't valid.  So my formula should be modified somehow.  On the other hand, I computed the displayed product over $p$'s of degree up to $15$, and got $0.8321...$, matching Robert Israel's computations.  So maybe my formula is a reasonable approximation to the truth.

Comment: For $p(x)\in\mathbb{F}_2[x]$ a prime, the condition $p|x^m+(1+x)^n$ is equivalent to some congruence condition on $m$ and $n$ modulo a divisor of $N(p)-1$. These moduli are not coprime for different $p$, so I don't think the conditions are independent.

Comment: That makes sense, but I can't find a small example where the conditions are dependent.  Perhaps this is because the congruence conditions aren't "random", but instead have the form $m\equiv k m_0$, $n\equiv k n_0$  for a single fixed choice of $m_0$ and $n_0$?

Comment: Write $p_1=x^4+x+1$, $p_2=x^4+x^3+1$, $p_3=x^2+x+1$. If $p_1p_2|x^m+(x+1)^n$, then $m\equiv n\equiv 0\mod{15}$, so necessarily $p_3|x^m+(1+x)^n$.

Comment: Nice!  Any ideas how to modify the probability computation then?

Comment: I can't think of a way to modify the computation to account for the correlation. I think we can show that the product is a lower bound on the true probability, though.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be a hard and interesting problem.  Here's a heuristic on the correct answer, but I have little hope that it can be made into a proof.  Below let $D$ denote a polynomial in ${\Bbb F}_2[x]$ and let $\mu(D)$ denote the Mobius function.  We will only be interested in $D$ that are coprime to $x(1+x)$.  For such $D$ consider the group generated by $x$ and $1+x$ in $({\Bbb F}_2[x]/D)^*$; denote this by $\langle x,1+x\rangle_D$ and its order by 
$|\langle x,1+x\rangle_D|$.  The conjectured probability is 
$$ 
\sum_{D, (D,x(1+x))=1} \frac{\mu(D)}{|\langle x, 1+x \rangle_D|^2}. 
$$

To see why this is, note that we can identify whether  $(f,g)=1$ by summing $\sum_{D|f, D|g} \mu(D)$.  Thus the problem asks for 
$$ 
\sum_{D, (D,x(1+x))=1} \mu(D) \Big( \frac{1}{(N+1)^2} \sum_{0 \le a, b\le N; D|x^a+(1+x)^b} 1\Big)^2. 
$$

The probability that $D$ divides $x^a+(1+x)^b$ is the same as the probability that 
$D$ divides $x^m (1+x)^n +1 = x^m (1+x)^n -1$.  Since $x^m (1+x)^n$ ranges uniformly over the elements of $\langle x,1+x \rangle_D$, this probability is clearly $1/|\langle x,1+x\rangle_D|$.  This justifies heuristically the conjecture.  The argument could be made precise by splitting $a$ and $b$ into intervals of size the order of $x$ in $({\Bbb F}_2[x]/D)^*$ and the order of $1+x$ there.  The trouble is that there will be an error of 
size $O(1/N)$ in doing so, and this cannot be controlled as the sum over $D$ includes exponentially many terms.

It seems plausible that the sum over $D$ in the conjecture converges, but I don't see any way to prove this.  It would be interesting to compute it numerically. One can get something rigorous by doing the above analysis with only those $D$ whose irreducible factors have degree below $\log N$ say.  In this way one obtains an upper bound for the desired probability.

Answer (score 4):

The probability that two random polynomials of large degree in F_2[t] are coprime is $\zeta(2)^{-1}$, or 1/2.  Your polynomials are not quite random; neither one is divisible by x or x+1.  The probability that two polynomials, both prime to x(x+1), are coprime, is obtained by removing the two corresponding local factors of the Euler product for $\zeta(2)$; in other words, without that restriction, there would be a common factor of x 1/4 of the time, and a common factor of (1+x) 1/4 of the time.  So the probability that two polynomials, both coprime to x(x+1), are coprime to each other is (4/3)*(4/3)*(1/2) = 8/9.  This is not quite what you get.  What happens when you try it with the variables ranging from 1 to N instead of 0 to N?

**Update:** Mike Zieve's answer is better than mine, so am I supposed to downvote mine, or what?

Comment: Interesting. Could you also include derivation for $\zeta(2)^{-1}$ or a reference?

Comment: There's something going on with the other primes. For example, $x^m$ and $(1+x)^n$ both run through all non-zero residue classes mod $(1+x+x^2)$, so the probability that $1+x+x^2$ divides $x^m + (1+x)^n$ is $\frac{1}{3}$, rather than $\frac{1}{4}$. It seems like the corrected Euler factor at $(1+x+x^2)$ should be $1-\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^2$.

Comment: The system won't let you downvote your own answer. Silly, isn't it!

Comment: "$\zeta(2)^{-1}$, or $1/2$"?